# Showing error while sending arraylist from servlet to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist, casting

I want to send a ArrayList object from servlet page to a jsp page.But there show an error in jsp page.

Below the piece of my servlet code

**Servlet**

```
ArrayList<Customer> al = new ArrayList<Customer>();
al = abs.viewCustomerReqRequest();
//Return type of viewCustomerReqRequest() method is ArrayList<Customer>

request.setAttribute("Customer_AL",al);
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("a_reg_request.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Below piece of my jsp page code

**JSP**

```
<%
  ArrayList<Customer> al = new ArrayList<Customer>();
  al = (ArrayList<Customer>) request.getAttribute("Customer_AL");
  Iterator<Customer> it = al.iterator();
%>
```

But In my jsp page there're showing an error like "**Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to `ArrayList<Customer>`**".

How can I remove this error from my jsp page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter to [`ServletRequest.setAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) is of type `Object`.

Once you pass the `List` as an `Object` parameter, it loses compile-time typing. The warning tells you about that. But it is a warning, not an error.

If you want to suppress the warning, you can use

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
al = (ArrayList<Customer>) request.getAttribute("Customer_AL");
```